# QT5.6.2 build not working due to strange "compiler generated file could not be created" error

Tags: c++, build, qt5, nmake

I am trying to compile 5.6.2. I have already compiled OpenSSL. `nmake` ran for about half an hour and then I get this error: (using quotes because they line-break which IMO improves readability; not sure if language is an issue here; if yes, I might translate certain lines...)

> cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zi -MTd -MP -W3 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 /Fd.obj\debug\qwebpd.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_STATICPLUGIN -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I......\3rdparty\libwebp -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\dec -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\enc -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\dsp -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\mux -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\utils -I......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\webp -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2\qtbase\include
>   -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2\qtbase\include\QtGui
>   -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2\qtbase\include\QtCore
>   -I.moc\debug -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\openssl\Release\include
>   -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015
>   -Fo.obj\debug\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2\qtimageformats\src\3rdparty\libwebp\src\dsp\upsampling_sse2.obj
>   ......\3rdparty\libwebp\src\dsp\upsampling_sse2.c
>       upsampling_sse2.c
>       C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2\qtimageformats\src\3rdparty\libwebp\src\dsp\upsampling_sse2.c
>   : fatal error C1083: Datei (vom Compiler generiert) kann nicht
>   geöffnet werden: "": Invalid argument
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"": Rückgabe-Code "0x1"
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
>       Stop.
>       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cd": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
>       Stop.

I have created the makefile before with:

> configure -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -opensource
>   -confirm-license -static -I "C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\openssl\Release\include"
>   -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib" -l Gdi32 -no-opengl -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS_DEBUG="C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\openssl_debug\Debug\lib\ssleay32.lib
>   C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\openssl_debug\Debug\lib\libeay32.lib"
>   OPENSSL_LIBS_RELEASE="C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\openssl\Release\lib\ssleay32.lib
>   C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\openssl\Release\lib\libeay32.lib"
>   -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -platform win32-msvc2015

Any idea what could we wrong here? What I could even check? I just do not understand this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the issue...

The windows path was too long. I created a junction directory to not be forced to move all files to other paths.

being in `C:\Users\Michael` I typed in the cmd:
`mklink /J /D tgqt C:\Users\Michael\Documents\vs13\Projects\Telegram\build\Libraries\qt5_6_2`

After `cd tgqt` I have just built from that directory et voilà...